# How to pass query parameters to a url inside a lambda function (netlify environment)

Tags: reactjs, api, lambda, netlify

When the user submit a search form I want to add the query parameter to the api url that is inside a lambda function.

I set up the netlify environment inside a react app and initialize a lambda function.Now I only get the response using hard-coded queries.

How can I pass parameters to the event.queryStringParameters?

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const API_PARAMS = qs.stringify(event.queryStringParameters);
  const { API_TOKEN, API_URL } = process.env;
  const URL = `${API_URL}search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&key=${API_TOKEN}&q=animals`;

  // Let's log some stuff we already have.
  console.log("Injecting token to", API_URL);
  console.log("logging event.....", event);
  console.log("Constructed URL is ...", URL);
  console.log('params are...', API_PARAMS);

  const pass = body => {
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    });
  };

  const get = () => {
    axios
      .get(URL)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        pass(response.data);
      })
      .catch(err => pass(err));
  };
  if (event.httpMethod == "GET") {
    get();
  }
};
```

App.js

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('.netlify/functions/youtube')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

this took me a minute to figure out but it's in the query string:

```
   let thing = 123;
   fetch(`/.netlify/functions/${filename}?item=${thing}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
```

if it's a post, you will need to parse it from the query but a regular get call you can pull it out of the `event.queryStringParameters`